# How to check if a range contains letter or not

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I would like to ask on how to use Isletter on a Range value.

Please see below my code:

```
If Range("$E$52").Value = **"Isletter"** Then

    Worksheets("Offloading_Tributary").Shapes("Object 115").Visible = False

        Else

    Worksheets("Offloading_Tributary").Shapes("Object 115").Visible = True

End If
```

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Comment: Can you add code tags please? Are you checking that cell consists of a single letter or contains a letter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect if the cell contents contains a letter, you could use:

```
If Range("$E$52").Value Like "*[a-zA-Z]*" Then
    Worksheets("Offloading_Tributary").Shapes("Object 115").Visible = False
Else
    Worksheets("Offloading_Tributary").Shapes("Object 115").Visible = True
End If
```

To detect if the cell contents consists only of a single letter:

```
If Range("$E$52").Value Like "[a-zA-Z]" Then
    Worksheets("Offloading_Tributary").Shapes("Object 115").Visible = False
Else
    Worksheets("Offloading_Tributary").Shapes("Object 115").Visible = True
End If
```

To detect if the cell contents consists only of a numeric value (and not empty, which it would consider to be zero and therefore numeric):

```
If IsNumeric(Range("$E$52").Value) And Range("$E$52").Value <> "" Then
    Worksheets("Offloading_Tributary").Shapes("Object 115").Visible = False
Else
    Worksheets("Offloading_Tributary").Shapes("Object 115").Visible = True
End If
```

Comment: Hi CLR, Is like checking if range has a value of a number and or a letter. Example if my range has a value of number then the macro will trigger and same if the value is a letter. Something like IsLetter. Also i'd like to check if the range has a value neither numeric or letter.

Comment: It's a string comparison function. If you use `Like "*[a-zA-Z]*"` then it would return `TRUE` if it can see any string of characters that include *at least* one alphabetical character. So the word "one" would return `True`, but "1" would not.

Comment: If you use `Like "[a-zA-Z]"` then it would return `TRUE` if it can see a string with a length of 1,containing a character that is one alphabetical character. So the word "one" would return `False`,  "1" would also return `False` but "Y" would return `True`.

Comment: Actually i'd like to check if the range has numberic neither  letter. Of course at the beginning  the range is blank. So if someone type in it used numeric or letter. Or if a range has drop down list. If someone picked a a word from that list neither containing a letter or number it will trigger the sub.

Comment: If you can give us a few examples of words that should make the shape visible, and some that should not, I'm sure we can help.

Comment: What if the range has a value of numeric how would i code that?

Comment: I've added that as part of my answer. (you might need to swap over your `.Visible = False` / `.Visible = True` depending on your intention.)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate

Comment: No problem. Hopefully one of those 3 (or a combination of them) serves as an answer. Don't forget to mark it answered if you're happy with it.